# How to direct a script in a particular folder

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to make a simple script where I need to give a full access for a certain folder inside the `Program Files`/`Program Files (x86)`.

`icacls` works perfectly but I need to open a `cmd` instance manually from the folder by using the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+ for the command to work.

```
icacls /grant Users:(OI)(CI)F
```

Just wonder if I could do it like this?

```
cmd /K "cd C:\Program Files\BITS"
```

Or if not available search in:

```
cmd /K "cd C:\Program Files (x86)\BITS"
```

Hope you could help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
IF EXIST C:\Program Files\BITS GOTO normal
IF EXIST C:\Program Files (x86)\BITS GOTO x86
echo no BITS directory found
pause
exit
:normal
cmd /K "cd C:\Program Files\BITS"
exit
:x86
cmd /K "cd C:\Program Files (x86)\BITS"
```

That should test if either of the folders exists, and open cmd from the right directory depending on which exists